# Loop troguh appointments in outlook stops at first match

Tags: c#

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` and I am trying to loop trough all the appointments that match a particular set of conditions:

1. To reduce the items I limit the search between two knows maximum dates
2. It has to contain an "ID"

Beside the additional regex that I don't know if it can be fitted in the `.Restrict`, the foreach loop interrupts at the first entry

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

        string filter1 = "[Start] >= '" + start.ToString("g") + "' AND [End] <= '" + DateTime.MaxValue.ToString("g") + "'";

        Outlook.Items calendarItems = personalCalendar.Items.Restrict(filter1);
        calendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
        calendarItems.Sort("[Start]", Type.Missing);

        string filter3 = "@SQL=" + "\"" + "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" + "\"" + " LIKE '%" + AppCode + "%'";

        Outlook.Items restrictedItems = calendarItems.Restrict(filter3);

        bool error_free = true;
        foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem apptItem in restrictedItems)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(apptItem.Subject);
            try
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(apptItem.Subject, @"^.*##ManaOrdini\d{1,}##.*$"))
                {
                    apptItem.Move(newCalendarFolder);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Si è verificato un errore durante la creazione dell'appuntamento. Errore: " + ex.Message);
                error_free = false;
            }
        }
```

Can anybody explain me why? Do I have to add a `goto` method to iterate untill no entry found?

EDIT
The variable `restrictedItems`  contains the following entries:

```
Subject "Reminder Ordine Numero:1\t##ManaOrdini1#"  System.String
Subject "Reminder Ordine Numero:1\t##ManaOrdini##"  System.String
Subject "Reminder Ordine Numero:1\t##ManaOrdini1222##"  System.String
Subject "Reminder Ordine Numero:1\t##ManaOrdini1##" System.String
```

EDIT 2

Ended up with this, basically I had to split in two parts:

1. Clone the results of the filters
2. Loop and move

   DateTime start = DateTime.Now.AddDays( - 2);

   ```
   string filter1 = "[Start] >= '" + start.ToString("g") + "' AND [End] <= '" + DateTime.MaxValue.ToString("g") + "'";

   Outlook.Items calendarItems = personalCalendar.Items.Restrict(filter1);
   calendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
   calendarItems.Sort("[Start]", Type.Missing);

   string filter3 = "@SQL=" + "\"" + "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" + "\"" + " LIKE '%" + AppCode + "%'";

   Outlook.Items restrictedItems = calendarItems.Restrict(filter3);

   bool error_free = true;
   int c = 0;
   List < Outlook.AppointmentItem > listaApp = new List < Outlook.AppointmentItem > ();

   foreach(Outlook.AppointmentItem apptItem in restrictedItems) {
       if (Regex.IsMatch(apptItem.Subject, @"^.*##ManaOrdini\d{1,}##.*$")) {
           listaApp.Add(apptItem);
           c++;
       }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
       try {
           listaApp[i].Move(newCalendarFolder);
       }
       catch(System.Exception ex) {
           MessageBox.Show("Si è verificato un errore durante la creazione dell'appuntamento. Errore: " + ex.Message);
           error_free = false;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that there are multiple items in your `restrictedItems` collection?

Comment: ***No, you don't need GOTO!*** I'm not familiar with the Outlook SDK, so I don't know what `apptItem.Move` does. But it *might*  modify the collection you are currently iterating, and thus causing an exception. Try adding a `try ... catch `  *around the loop*  and check if there is any exception thrown. Other than that, you could try attaching a debugger which will break when an uncaught exception is thrown. And you would also be able, to inspect, that `restrictedItems` does indeed contain more than one element ...

Comment: @Chobo No, is it restrictedItems.Count? Nevertheless I am sure because I have two appointments in the same day that match the condition, moving between calendars put the moved one at the end and so one time each run the other is moved

Comment: @derpirscher tried to put the try outside the foreach loop with catch (System.Exception ex) and no error returned

Comment: When debugging through your code, set a breakpoint on your `Outlook.Items restrictedItems = calendarItems.Restrict(filter3);` line. When your application stops, step over and look at your `restrictedItems` variable to see what's contained in it using the Locals tab.

Comment: @Chobo Sorry, I had some issues with the debuggnig. At the line you mentioned varibale was null, while stopping at the next line returned the correct values. These are found items: `Subject "Reminder Ordine Numero:1\t##ManaOrdini1#" System.String`  `Subject "Reminder Ordine Numero:1\t##ManaOrdini##" System.String`  ` Subject "Reminder Ordine Numero:1\t##ManaOrdini1222##" System.String`  `Subject "Reminder Ordine Numero:1\t##ManaOrdini1##" System.String`  Which are the correct ones, with the regex it is supposed to find only the last two items.